# How to add a filed in MongoDB array

Tags: django, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a doc like this

```
{
studentname: Ravi,
Adrress : Something,
marks: [
{exam:first, M1:200, M2:300}
{exam:sec,M1:300,M2:500}
}
```

I want to add Mark M3:500 in exam: first using update.How can i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

I got answer after some search:

```
db.UserModule.update(
{'marks.exam': 'first' },
{'$set': {'marks.$.M3': 500}}, 
true 

)
```